# remove characters before and after separator(character) in python

Tags: python

Remove all characters before and after the specified character, I tried 1st part i am able to do that next occurrence the code is not working.

I tried using the split string function to trip off the characters before and after separator, after 1st occurrence the solution is not working

```
tring = "www.xyz.com"
sep = '.'
rest = string.split(sep, 1)
print(rest)
```

The finally output supposed to be xyz.

Comment: why not `string.split(sep)[1]` ?

Comment: yes, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

```
string = "www.xyz.com"
sep = '.'
rest = string.split(sep)
print(rest[1])
```

**output**

```
xyz
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're certain about structure of string, use

```
rest = string.split(sep)[1]
```

It will split at all occurrences of `.` and from the resulting list, return you the sub-string at index 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
tring = "www.xyz.com"

step_1 = lambda string, sep : string[string.find(sep)+1:]

result = lambda string, sep: step_1(string, '.')[: step_1(string, sep).find(sep)]


res = result(tring, '.')

print(res)
```

Output

```
xyz
```

This works for any string, two return the string between two separators